# return JSONObject with java app engine

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a cloud endpoint function that returns a json string as response. An api endpoint makes an http request to the cloud function. How can I return the json string response as it is. I tried the following(just as an example)

```
@ApiMethod(
            name = "json",
            httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET
    )
    public JsonObject json()
    {
        String item = "{\"name\":\"Josh\",\"sex\":\"male\"}";
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        return jsonParser.parse(item).getAsJsonObject();

    }
```

and I get the following message

```
WARNING: exception occurred while invoking backend method
[INFO] GCLOUD: java.io.IOException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject (through reference chain: endpoints.repackaged.com.google.gson.JsonObject["asInt"]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject
```

I understand JSONObject is not part of the supported returned type, I just want to know how I can just output the json string response from the endpoint just as it is

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to wrap your JSON into a String (in your endpoint) and return the wrapper object. You wrapper object could be a simple POJO with only one String attribute. Then on your API consumer side, you just read the string (representing your JSON) and use it as you wish.